# Json getting corrupted over http POST when recieved by alfresco webscript

Tags: java, json, rest, alfresco

I am working on developing a REST-API, ie Alfresco based java-backed webscript.
Where I am supposed to pass a Json as POST request parameter field.
When I try to retrieve the parameter field on server side using:
     webScriptRequest.getParameter(json);
I am recieving a corrupted Json.

Based on analysis its getting corrupted because of one of the below fields or may be combination of them,
I don't know exactly which special character is causing this corruption problem. 
Can anybody help me out in figuring-out this issue.

My hunch is some special character combination in below field is corrupting the json:

- `2014-04-23T13:42:24.962-04:00`
- `/case/77777777/doc/x-search-found.pdf`
- `http://temp.com/doc/source/url`
- `/case/77777777/doc/my-findings.pdf`
- `2014-04-23T13:42:24.962-04:00`
- `"docGroupNames": ["working", "suggested"]`

If I remove above fields, I start receiving the healthy json on server side.

Below is the sample JSON:

```
{
    "documentAlias": "DocNameForTmngUiDisplay",
    "modifiedByUserId": "User XYZ",
    "sourceSystem": "TMNG",
    "sourceMedia": "electronic",
    "sourceMedium": "upload",
    "accessLevel": "public",
    "scanDate": "2014-04-23T13:42:24.962-04:00",
    "docList": [
        {
            "documentId": "/case/77777777/doc/x-search-found.pdf",
            "metadata": {
                "modifiedByUserId": "User XYZ",
                "documentAlias": "nickname",
                "sourceMedia": "paper",
                "docSourceUrl": "http://test/doc/source/url",
                "docCategory": "web"
            }
        },
        {
            "documentId": "/case/77777777/doc/my-findings.pdf",
            "metadata": {
                "sourceMedium": "fax",
                "accessLevel": "public",
                "scanDate": "2014-04-23T13:42:24.962-04:00",
                "evidenceSourceTypeId": "123",
                "docGroupNames": [
                    "working",
                    "suggested"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Additional Disclosure:
This looks like REST-Client issue, try changing your Rest Client is one probable solution to json corruption issue.

This issue is happening specifically on SoapUI 5.0.0 Above issue is NOT happening on DHC 0.7.2.2 (Chrome based rest client extension)

Comment: Your JSON is valid and Alfresco should have no problems parsing it. How is the JSON corrupted? What error do you get?

Comment: Here is the corrupted json that I am receiving on servers side:
 {"documentAlias":"DocNameForTmngUiDisp= lay","modifiedByUserId":"User 
XYZ",="sourceSystem":"TMNG","sourceMedia":"electronic",="sourceMedium":"upload","accessL= evel":"public","scanDate":"2014-04-23T13:42:24.962-0= 
4:00","docList":[{="documentId":"/case/77777777/doc/x-search-found.pdf", 
="metadata":{"m= odifiedByUserId":"User XYZ","documentAlia= 
s":"nickname","sourceMedia":"paper",="docSourceUrl":"http://test/doc/sou 
rce/url",="docCategory":"web"=}},{="documentId":"/case/77777777/doc/my-f 
indings.pdf",="metadata":{"sour.....

Comment: So, you can notice in above comment, system automatically added '=' character at random places.. and its NOT a well formatted json anymore...

Comment: can you please add your code??

Comment: @Krutik Jayswal.. I tried my best to include the maximum possible code...
stackoverflow.com question uploading is NOT allowing me to pastte more code that what I was able to put here...
If I put more code then the validation message keeps coming put that I need to put more context with the code and text editor formatting rules just does NOT allow me to proceed further with the posting of the question...

Comment: One way to by-pass the above issue: 
This looks like REST-Client issue, try changing your Rest Client is one probable solution to json corruption issue.

This issue is happening specifically on SoapUI 5.0.0 Above issue is NOT happening on DHC 0.7.2.2 (Chrome based rest client extension)

Comment: I cant help with only your json response.I will need files of alfresco webscript, what you have written in that and code which you are using for calling alfresco webscript.If possible upload file in google cloud or some where else.

Comment: @Krutik Jayswal.. One alfresco side its AbstractWebScript and very first line its reading a corrupted json:
String metadata = webScriptRequest.getParameter(incomingJsonPayload);

Comment: Without full information I wont be able to help you.my skype is krutik.jayswal